# What is the best method to immobilize a Godzilla-like monster?

Tags: creature-design, military-defense

Suppose a Godzilla-like monster landed on the shore of California and heading towards the city business district, despite not being able to shoot atomic breath, nor discharging laser beams from its body. How could the military using modern day tech to halt its rampage?

Please note that the monster possess accelerated healing factor second only to Marvel X-men's Wolverine! When provoked the monster activates its second ability which mimic the octopus's [chromatophores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatophore) which covers its entire body that's already impervious to [M203](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M203_grenade_launcher) a grenade launcher. Don't kill it! If the blood circulation for cooling its internal nuclear reactor ceases it undergoes nuclear meltdown! You have been warned.

Comment: I have no idea what that octopus covering thing is. Isn't it just a camoflage chameleon effect?

Comment: So if its blood cools it goes into nuclear meltdown?

Comment: @Bellerophon: my apologies for my poor English I meant the blood circulation prevents meltdown!

Comment: @Sky: yup but I like to throw in some heavy words to make me sounds like a pro if u don't mind.

Comment: @user6760  I tried to improve the question abit, change it back if you don't like it.

Comment: @user6760 Btw why would you want to immbilize a walking nuclear reactor? My edits disappeared, does someone have to review it?

Comment: @Sky: erm... I don't know maybe it is rampaging around the city stepping on people!

Comment: Maybe it really wants that fast food

Comment: I edited the post—check to make sure I unraveled the first paragraph OK and put the period in the right place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its always useful to use an enemy's strength against it, and physics. If we're talking giant monsters though...

Great big pit of quicksand or some non [newtonian fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Newtonian_fluid#Oobleck). Find something that the monster likes, draw it in, let it sink in.

Quicksand is probably more useful - you can control its properties with water flow - as the mythbusters did, and drain it to 'lock' the creature in a bunch of sand.

Oobleck would allow the creature to sink in, and react by stiffening to more violent movement.

Of course. *Then what*

But that's outside the cope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

### Don't provoke it

Get the whole arsenal of Chinook helicopters and have them start hanging deep fried cow below them. The Godzilla creature will be enticed by the smell and start following them. Now just lure it back to the sea and feed it so that it goes away. If it comes back, just give it more fried cow, fish or anything really. Costly but peaceful.

### Get a lot military grade rope and Godzilla-sized bolas

Yeah, one rope won't do much. But if you get an entire army tieing ropes around it, it will fall... eventually. It worked with gulliver, should be totally fine here. Might take a lot of effort but meh.

### Godzilla-sized Taser

It's a living thing. Which means it has a nervous system and nerves. Shock it till its paralyzed and then cart it off to the Chernobyl where you can kill it safely(maybe) or keep it somewhere so it will come back to bite you in the arse after it gets really angry.

### Call Mothra or Ultraman or Superman

Because there's pretty much nothing you can do and require Phlebotinium to fight Phlebotinium. You can't kill it, can't provoke it(?) and [The JSDF](http://giantmonsters.wikia.com/wiki/J.S.D.F.) is useless.

Comment: **header format code** awareness prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how the healing works (does anything prevent it?) and what the limits of its toughness are.

It's immune to grenades, but larger explosives should still work. Even if the skin is effectively impenetrable, shock waves could break bones, pulp muscles etc. - so you should still be able to temporarily immobilize it by damaging the legs with e.g. missiles from aircraft.

The legs will heal, but you can keep attacking, and try various types of attacks on the wounds themselves to find something that stops the healing (try something like napalm, if that doesn't work step up to chlorine trifluoride, maybe try a ton of liquid nitrogen to cryo-freeze the cells, etc.)

If nothing does, then keep blasting it to keep it immobilized while you build restraints (net/chains/etc.) strong enough to hold it. Trap it in the net while it's temporarily immobilized by limb destruction.

Once it's immobilized in a lasting way, either find a way to use its nuclear bio-processes for civilization's benefit, or if it's just too much to handle, use a large ship to drag it far out to sea and kill it there (water is good radiation shielding, so a melting-down Godzilla on the seafloor shouldn't cause much damage outside its very immediate vicinity).

Answer (score 1):

Stinkbombs!
Find a smell it dislikes, by throwing smelly stuff at its face from helicopters (ideally, your monster has short arms).
Once you find what it hates and will avoid, use that to herd it away from populated areas and preferably back to the sea.
Stockpile your stinkbombs for future visits!

Comment: Or alternatively, aim sound cannons right at its eardrums.